# Delete duplicates based on varchar in another row. Eliminate terminated staff from active roster

Tags: drop-duplicates

I want to create a roster that shows only active staff.  All staff are listed in a table, active staff with no termination have one row in the table.  Terminated staff have two rows of data. Employee status is wages or term.  How can I get one row of only active staff?  Each staff member has a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using?

I'm assuming you're using Python, and using pandas to process data.
Also, whenever possible, sharing a sample data enables other users
to help you more efficiently.

**Please, if possible, edit your question adding a little more context to your question, so that others can help you more efficiently!**

I've developed the code below, trying to re-create your problem based on what I could infer about the data from your question.

```py
# == Necessary Imports ===============================================
import pandas as pd

# == Generate sample dataframe =======================================
# For our sample, employees 3, 7, and 9 will represent the terminated
# employees.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "memberID": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9],
        "status": [
            "wages",
            "wages",
            "wages",  # <-- Employee 3 terminated
            "term",   # <-- Employee 3 terminated
            "wages",
            "wages",
            "wages",
            "wages",  # <-- Employee 7 terminated
            "term",   # <-- Employee 7 terminated
            "wages",
            "wages",  # <-- Employee 9 terminated
            "term",   # <-- Employee 9 terminated
        ],
    }
)

# == Solution ==============================================================
df.loc[
    df["memberID"].isin(
        df["memberID"]
        .value_counts()
        .to_frame("count")
        .loc[lambda xdf: xdf["count"] < 2, :]
        .index
    ),
    :,
]
# Returns:
#
#    memberID status
# 0         1  wages
# 1         2  wages
# 4         4  wages
# 5         5  wages
# 6         6  wages
# 9         8  wages
```

### Notes

Basically, my approach was to use [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to find the number of times each `"memberID"` appears on the dataframe.
Then I chained a `.loc` call to filter for employees with less than 2 appearances on the dataframe and filtered those `"memberID"` on the original `df`.

In summary, the solution uses three methods from pandas:

1. [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html): count the number of times each value from a pandas Series gets repeated.
2. [`pandas.Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html): transform a pandas Series to DataFrame (useful for chaining multiple operations together).
3. [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html): used to filter employees that appeared only once in the data. Then used a second time to filter the original `df` to only consider those employees that weren't terminated.